# Running a script on a specific tab, triggered by time?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been trying to get the 2nd tab of my sheet to enter a static date stamp **after** a script triggered on edit moves that row from the first tab to the second.

After hours of trying different things and scouring Google, I'm stuck...

Here's my script being triggered every hour:

```
  function setDate() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = s.getSheetByName('COMPLETE');
var r = sheet.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 11 ) {
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
  if( nextCell.getValue() === '' )
    nextCell.setValue(new Date());
 }
}
```

Obviously it's one of the published examples from Google that I've turned into Frankenstein's Monster... How can I get this date stamp to trigger on the 2nd sheet (COMPLETE) every hour?

Comment: Consider that when there is no user using the sheet, `getActiveCell()` returns cell A1. If you want to timestamp a row based on some action, consider using an `on edit` triggered function. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

Comment: @tehhowch I tried that, but because ALL the data on this sheet is moved there on edit by a script, it doesn't consider this sheet as being edited... since it's edited by the script and not by a user.

Comment: So modify that script to also write the time?